# SSIS: How to pass recordset from Execute SQL task to SMTP Mail task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Here are my requirements:

- update rows in a table based on some logic.
- email the rows that have been updated
- cannot create base tables in database

In T-SQL, this is very simple:

```
UPDATE table
SET Col = NewValue
OUTPUT INSERTED.Col1 INTO #temp
WHERE <some logic>

sp_send_dbmail -query"select * from #temp" <etcetera>
```

This seems to be problematic in SSIS. I create an Execute SQL task to perform the update, but how to pass the recordset into the SMTP Mail task?

Comment: Store the outputted dataset as an SSIS package-level variable of Object type.

Comment: I see. I was hoping to be able to select the Object variable as the MessageSource in the Send Mail task, but once I select Variable as the MessageSourceType, only the String variables are dipsplayed. To convert the Object variable recordset into a string that can be used in the MessageSource, I assume I need to write my own Script task?

Comment: Well, either that, or you need to modify your SQL so that instead of returning a resultset it returns the string that you want to email.

Comment: This seems to be yet another case of "do it in T-SQL because it's messy/difficult/impossible to do in SSIS".